# How to make a Clicking BOT?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to make a program

What this script should do is:

1. First go a webpage "www.site.com/index.php"
2. Then start clicking every URL in the site until it matches with "www.site.com/sitemap.xml"
3. Then the bot should come back to my site and say that "sitemap.xml has been found".

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: That is a pretty, um... inefficient way to find a link to `sitemap.xml`. :) What is your final goal with this?

Comment: I'm basically trying to locate the requested site's sitemap.xml so that the webmaster can be sure of it !

Comment: @user then why not just make a request to `sitemap.xml` and see what it returns?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) for PHP. With it, you will be able to get the contents of a URL in a string. Then you can examine it, find the other links, and do the same until you find it.

--

It doesn't matter if the URL is shortened, CURL will get you to the actual page, there are options to follow redirects.

Also, if you already know the URL that the webpage you're looking for is in, you can just get call curl with that url and check if it exists.

Comment: No,I'm not looking to download anything.Just click the URL and check if the URL is matching.I'm clicking the URL because it can be shortened by some URL shortners !

Comment: I am sure there are a lot out there, here is an examples web page: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php